# array of latest files from txt read all files

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

I have a text file with multiple entries. The format is fixed and is `name_version_versionNumber`.

```
**example.txt**
cool_name_A_001
something_else_WIP_002
something_else_001
cool_name_B_002
other_thing_010
other_thing_006
```

The return list should eliminate WIP entries, and provide the most current (highest number) version. the output for the text file above should be

```
cool_name_A_001
cool_name_B_002
other_thing_010
something_else_001
```

So far, I have

```
#import files
x = File.readlines("path to txt file").delete_if {|x| x.scan(/[WIP]../).include? "WIP"}.sort

#include latest copy only
#include latest copy only
def latest_version(x)
list = []
i = 0
while i<x.length
    if list.map {|x| x.scan(/\D+/)}.flatten.include? x[i].scan(/\D+/)
        zet = list.map {|x| x.scan(/\D+/)}.flatten.rindex x[i].scan(/\D+/)
        if list[zet].scan(/\d+/) > x[i].scan(/\d+/)
            i+=1
        else 
            list[zet] = x[i]
            i+=1
        end
    elsif x[i].scan(/\D+/) == x[i+1].scan(/\D+/)
        if x[i].scan(/\d+/) > x[i+1].scan(/\d+/)
            list << x[i]
            i+=1
        else
            list << x[i+1]
            i+=1
        end
    else
        list << x[i]
        i+=1
    end
  end
  list
end

puts latest_version(x)
```

I receive the following error

```
rb:10:in `latest_version': private method `scan' called for 114:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

The error method works in irb and cannot figure out why the error? Also, cannot tell if the logic does what is desired outcome. Please help! Thank you :)

```
1.9.3p374 :098 > y
 => ["something_SA_R33\n", "whatever_SA_R012\n", "anything_SB_R012\n"]
1.9.3p374 :099 > y.map {|x| x.scan(/\d+/)}.flatten
 => ["33", "012", "012"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use something like:

```
data = %w[
  cool_name_A_001
  something_else_WIP_002
  something_else_001
  cool_name_B_002
  other_thing_010
  other_thing_006
]

data.reject{ |s| s['_WIP_'] }.group_by{ |s| s[/\A(.+)_\d+/, 1] }.map{ |k, v| v.max }.sort
[
    [0] "cool_name_A_001",
    [1] "cool_name_B_002",
    [2] "other_thing_010",
    [3] "something_else_001"
]
```

To read from a file replace `data` with `x = File.readlines("path to txt file")`.

But that's just me.

Comment: It's definitely a goal of mine to make code look this good! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. I've programmed in a lot of languages, but Ruby is my favorite ever. It's expressive, it allows us to be concise while maintaining readability. The term "zen-like" applies so often to code I've seen, where I have to sit amazed as I look at it. Simplicity, with power, is what we look for. Occasionally I stumble into it. :-)

Comment: This is great for learning, shows I need to be more familiar with Enumerables (was fixated on Array methods) and my need to practice Regex and/or utilize Rubular. May whoever knocked down your answer be afflicted with sarcoidosis and die of malnutrition after they can no longer find a vein from their sclerosis.

Comment: Downvotes are non-issues. If an answer is good, even if it wasn't selected, it'll still get upvotes over time. Enumerable is cool. Learn how to implement Comparable and Enumerable in your own classes and you gain a huge number of useful methods.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to sort them in reverse order, then loop through all the elements removing all the WIP elements and saving the first of each group (match on ^/(.*?)_\d{3}$/)?  All that scanning seems pretty brittle.

Comment: Yeah, I think the way it is above is really slow and unnecessary. I'll look into your suggestion, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's very questionably is it really need to create such complex method. Ruby has a lot of methods to create life easier.

So, your one of your mistakes is to use same names for method argument `latest_version(x)` and for map iteration `list.map{|x| ... }`. It is not very good practice